# isspace and isalpha isn't counting

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to count the number of vowels, consonants, digits, and spaces in an entered string. It's only counting the number of digits. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void counter(char string[], int count[]){
    int check_letter, check_digit, check_space;
    for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++){
        check_letter = isalpha(string[i]);
        if(check_letter == 1){
            string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
            if(string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' ||
                    string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u'){
                count[0] = count[0] + 1;
            } else{
                count[1] = count[1] + 1;
            }
        }
        check_digit = isdigit(string[i]);
        if (check_digit == 1){
            count[2] = count[2] + 1;
        }
        check_space = isspace(string[i]);
        if(check_space == 1){
            count[3] = count[3] + 1;
        }
    }
}

main(){
    char string[100] = {};
    int count[4] = {};
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin.get(string, 100);
    cin.get();
    cout << string;
    counter(string, count);
    cout << "There are " << count[0] << " vowels.\nThere are " << count[1] <<
            " consonants.\nThere are " << count[2] << " digits.\nThere are " <<
            count[3] << " spaces.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your program and it works fine for me. You can check the return values of isalpha() isdigit() directly in the if () statement as if they were bools.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void counter(char string[], int count[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++){
        if(isalpha(string[i])){
            string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
            if(string[i] == 'a' || string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' ||
                    string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u'){
                count[0] = count[0] + 1;
            } else{
                count[1] = count[1] + 1;
            }
        }
        if (isdigit(string[i])){
            count[2] = count[2] + 1;
        }
        if(isspace(string[i])){
            count[3] = count[3] + 1;
        }
    }
}

main(){
    char string[100] = {};
    int count[4] = {};
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin.get(string, 100);
    cin.get();
    cout << string;
    counter(string, count);
    cout << "There are " << count[0] << " vowels.\nThere are " << count[1] <<
            " consonants.\nThere are " << count[2] << " digits.\nThere are " <<
            count[3] << " spaces.";
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but then `int check_letter, check_digit, check_space;` is of no use...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the assumption that `isalpha`, `isdigit` etc. return `1` when they match: their docs say they return a non-zero value for "true" and zero for "false".

For example, from [std::isalpha docs here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha):

> **Return value**
>
> Non-zero value if the character is an alphabetic character, zero otherwise.

If you store the results in a `bool`, or test them directly in a boolean context (e.g. the `if (...)` condition, then the conversion will be done for you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `check_letter`, `check_digit` and `check_space` should all be `bool` and not `int`.

So, change `bool check_letter, check_digit, check_space;` as well as `if(check_letter)` instead of `if(check_letter == 1)` and so on.

Also please bare in mind that "string" is not a very smart way of naming a variable...